# Cannot get the standard deviation, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, math

I'm basically trying to use an array, which is data that is read from a file, and then using that array calculate the mean and standard deviation from the data.

I just can't seem to get the right number.

```
static public double[][] calcStats(String[][] x) throws IOException {
  double[][] array = new double[7][2];
  double total = 0, std_dev = 0, amount = 0;
  int row2 = 0;
  for (int row = 1; row < x.length; row++) {
    array[row2][0] = (total);
    array[row2][1] = Math.sqrt(amount);
    amount = 0;
    total = 0;
    if (row >= 2) {
      row2++;
    }
    for (int col = 1; col < x[row].length; col++) {
      total += Integer.parseInt(x[row][col]);
      if (col == 4) {
        total = (total / 4);
      }
    }
    for (int col = 1; col < x[row].length; col++) {
      std_dev = (Integer.parseInt(x[row][col])) - (total);
      std_dev = Math.pow(std_dev, 2);
      amount = +std_dev;
      std_dev = 0;
      if (col == 4) {
        amount = (amount / 27);
      }
    }
  }
  array[row2][0] = (total);
  return array;
}
```

Comment: Standard deviation is typically on one dimensional data, what is the significance of the row/column structure?

Comment: Its hard to work out what half the code does or why it is there.  Perhaps if you try to step through the code in a debugger you will see what it is really doing, not what you think it is doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays in Java start at 0. You are starting your loops at 1. That means that you are missing the first element of each array.

As per Marko Topolnik's suggestion, I should point out that I changed `amount =+ std_dev;` in your original code to `amount += std_dev;`. Now that I think about it, that was an invalid edit, since the original code was an additional problem (besides the loop limits). I rolled the edit back to Marco's version.

Comment: With your edit of the code you didn't correct the "correction", but introduce a "correction", changing OP's original code semantics. Probably for the better, though, but in a way that is not helpful to OP. You should clearly point out that change in your answer.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - True. The original code had `amount =+ std_dev;`. That was clearly a typo for `amount += std_dev;`. The earlier edit had changed it to `amount = +std_dev;`, which was just as wrong as the original.

Comment: My edit was, as the edit comment explains, a code reformatting. Of course it is just as wrong, that is the point. We don't answer questions by editing them.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - I agree. I rolled back my edit. However, reformatting that line hid the fact that `=+` was probably a typo for `+=`.

Comment: On the other hand, it made the mistake more clearly visible, since a lot of people will skim over `=+` without even noticing it is in fact not `+=`. Anyone studying the code semantics will notice the **error** better than the **typo**.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I might write it without changing the method signature.

```
public static double[][] calcStats(String[][] x) {
    double[][] array = new double[x.length][2];
    for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {
        String[] xrow = x[row];
        double total = 0;
        for (String s : xrow)
            total += Integer.parseInt(s);
        double average = total / xrow.length;

        double sqrTotal = 0;
        for (String s : xrow) {
            double d = Integer.parseInt(s) - total;
            sqrTotal += d * d;
        }
        array[row][0] = average;
        array[row][1] = Math.sqrt(sqrTotal);
    }
    return array;
}
```

or in a single pass as

```
public static double[][] calcStats(String[][] x) {
    double[][] array = new double[x.length][2];
    for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {
        String[] xrow = x[row];
        double sum = 0, sq_sum = 0;
        for (String s : xrow) {
            int d = Integer.parseInt(s);
            sum += d;
            sq_sum += d * d;
        }
        double mean = sum / xrow.length;
        double variance = sq_sum / xrow.length - mean * mean;
        array[row][0] = mean;
        array[row][1] = Math.sqrt(variance);
    }
    return array;
}
```